# Why does alignmentGuide behave differently for vertical and horizontal?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why is it that when increasing the alignment in the horizontal the red circle (thing being aligned) moves relative to it's "original spot", but when the vertical alignment is increased, the "original spot" moves relative to the circle?

Also, why when aligning horizontal does the alignment expand the `VStack`, but when increasing the alignment on the vertical, the `VStack` does not expand.

[image]

```swift
struct CircleOffsetView: View {
    
    let alignment: Alignment = .center
    let relative: UnitPoint = .center
    
    @State var widthOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var heightOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .alignmentGuide(alignment.horizontal, computeValue: { dimension in
                    dimension.width / 2 + widthOffset
                })
                .alignmentGuide(alignment.vertical, computeValue: { dimension in
                    dimension.height / 2 + heightOffset
                })
                .border(Color.black)
            
            Text("Width Offset: \(widthOffset)")
            Text("Height Offset: \(heightOffset)")
            
            Slider(value: $widthOffset, in: -150...150).padding()
            Slider(value: $heightOffset, in: -150...150).padding()
            
            Button("Reset") {
                widthOffset = 0
                heightOffset = 0
            }.padding()
            
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.red, width: 5)
        .padding()
        

    }
}
```

Comment: You are using wrong tool, the `alignmentGuide` is not designed for what you are looking! you can use `position` or `offset`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`alignmentGuide` is meant to change offset according to the parent `HStack` or `VStack` **alignment**. And to the first argument of `alignmentGuide` you should only pass alignment of the parent container to make it work.

In this case `VStack` has a default value of `Alignment.center.vertical`, that's why your first `alignmentGuide` works. If you add explicit `VStack(alignment: .leading)`, even `Alignment.center.vertical` will take no effect too.

`alignmentGuide` with `Alignment.center.horizontal` will only work inside `HStack(alignment: .center)`.

```
HStack(alignment: .center) {
    Circle()
        .foregroundColor(.red)
        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
        .border(Color.black)
        .alignmentGuide(Alignment.center.horizontal, computeValue: { dimension in
            dimension.width / 2 + widthOffset
        })
        .alignmentGuide(Alignment.center.vertical, computeValue: { dimension in
            dimension.height / 2 + heightOffset
        })
    VStack {
        Text("Width Offset: \(widthOffset)")
        Text("Height Offset: \(heightOffset)")
        
        Slider(value: $widthOffset, in: -150...150).padding()
        Slider(value: $heightOffset, in: -150...150).padding()
        
        Button("Reset") {
            widthOffset = 0
            heightOffset = 0
        }.padding()
    }
}
.padding()
.border(Color.red, width: 5)
.padding()
```

[image]

Check out about alignment guides in this [article](https://swiftui-lab.com/alignment-guides/)

I'm not sure why `border` gets moved in your case, probably the it's using `HStack` inside to build itself.

In terms of vertical offset inside a `VStack` it's not much clear what is your expected result.

1. You can move your item with `.offset`, but in this case the view will go out of bounds:

```
Circle()
    .foregroundColor(.red)
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .border(Color.black)
    .offset(x: widthOffset, y: heightOffset)
```

[image]

2. If you need to move your view vertically affecting bounds, you can use two spacers:

```
Spacer(minLength: 0).frame(height: max(0, heightOffset))
Circle()
    .foregroundColor(.red)
    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    .border(Color.black)
    .alignmentGuide(Alignment.center.horizontal, computeValue: { dimension in
        dimension.width / 2 + widthOffset
    })
Spacer(minLength: 0).frame(height: max(0, -heightOffset))
```

[image]

3. Some other result you're expecting to see?

Answer (score 0):

Here the right way of coding with offset:

```
struct CircleOffsetView: View {
    
    let alignment: Alignment = .center
    let relative: UnitPoint = .center
    
    @State var widthOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    @State var heightOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.red)
                .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                .offset(x: widthOffset, y: heightOffset) // <<: Here!
                .border(Color.black)
            
            Text("Width Offset: \(widthOffset)")
            Text("Height Offset: \(heightOffset)")
            
            Slider(value: $widthOffset, in: -150...150).padding()
            Slider(value: $heightOffset, in: -150...150).padding()
            
            Button("Reset") {
                widthOffset = 0
                heightOffset = 0
            }.padding()
            
        }
        .padding()
        .border(Color.red, width: 5)
        .padding()

    }
}
```